# The sorting in the app with fragments

Tags: java, android, sql, android-fragments

I make the application "Phone book". 
The application has a menu, which is sorting by name or category. I do it like this in MainActivity:

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
Fragment lvFragSortBy = new ListViewFragment();

switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.menuSortOrderName:
        item.setChecked(true);

        bundle.putString("sortBy", "name");

        lvFragSortBy.setArguments(bundle);
        getFragmentManager()
        .beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.fragContainer, lvFragSortBy)
        .commit();
        return true;

    case R.id.menuSortOrderCategory:
        item.setChecked(true);

        bundle.putString("sortBy", "category");
        lvFragSortBy.setArguments(bundle);
        getFragmentManager()
        .beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.fragContainer, lvFragSortBy)
        .commit();

        return true;
```

In ListViewFragment:

```
Bundle sortBundle = getArguments();
if (sortBundle != null) {
    orderBy = sortBundle.getString("sortBy");
}
```

And then:

```
protected ArrayList<Contact> doInBackground(Void... params) {
    try {
        db = new DbWorker(ctx);
        contacts = (ArrayList<Contact>) db.selectAllContacts(orderBy);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Exception in AsyncTask.doInBackground");
    }
    return contacts;
}
```

This code works fine but I would like to know can it be done better?
Maybe there's another way.

Comment: "*This code works fine but I would like to know can it be done better?*" - Maybe better suited to codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: What do you expect from "can it be done better"? Currently you implement a kind of array-adapter that keeps all contacts in memory. this is easy to implement/maintain/understand but has drawbacks with memory consuption and performance if you have many contacts. A cursor-adapter based solution is more difficuilt to understand/learn but is fast and memory efficient. Which one is *better*? "Fast with probaly premature unnecessary optimisation" or "easy to understand"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everybody, but I found the answer here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/147878/the-sorting-in-the-app-with-fragments/147881#147881

For proper operation of the fragments, you must use newInstance() pattern.